# Load Custom KeyBoard Automatically without touching EditText in Android

Tags: android

I have defined CustomKeyBoard in keyboard.xml file under 'xml' folder and added this keyboard.xml in activity_layout.xml. I want my CustomkKeyboard should be loaded automatically when my activity starts, but it is loading when i am touching EditText. My code is

```
private CustomKeyboardView mKeyboardView;
private View mTargetView;
private Keyboard mKeyboard;
mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard);
    mTargetView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_2d_res);
    mTargetView.setFocusable(true);
    mTargetView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            showKeyboardWithAnimation();
            return true;
        }
    });

    mKeyboardView = (CustomKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(this));
}

private void showKeyboardWithAnimation() {
    if (mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Add2d.this, R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
        mKeyboardView.showWithAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to load Custom Keyboard with out touching edittext?

Comment: Call `showKeyboardWithAnimation();` directly from onCreate()?

Answer (score 0):

you can call showKeyboardWithAnimation() in onCreate() method of your activity you should also call edittext.requestfocus()

Answer (score 0):

Animations start on views having the focus. Override `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus).